# How to get correct value from checked()?

Tags: functions, custom-field

I am trying to create 2 raido buttons as a category custom field, and in function.php I do:

```
$feat = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, '_feat', true ); 

<input name="feat" type="radio" value="0" <?php checked( '0' ); ?> />Si<br>
<input name="feat" type="radio" value="1" <?php checked( '1' ); ?> />No
```

And then I do

```
if ( isset( $_POST['feat'] ) )
  update_term_meta( $_POST['tag_ID'], '_feat', $_POST['feat'] );
```

But I always get "No" as checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `checked()` is to output a `checked="checked"` attribute *based on a current value*. By using it the way you're using it there you're forcing `Si` to never be checked and `No` to always be checked.

So what you want to do is use both arguments of [`checked()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) to compare the value of the input to the current value:

```
<input name="feat" type="radio" value="0" <?php checked( $feat, '0' ); ?> />Si<br>
<input name="feat" type="radio" value="1" <?php checked( $feat, '1' ); ?> />No
```

With that change if `$feat` is `'0'` then the first checked will run, and if it's `'1'` the second will run.